# Existing Java Web App and Spring STS (Spring 3)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Is it possible to take a project that I've been working on , import it into Spring STS and apply all the goodies that STS provides for easy Spring development to the project? For example, I'd like to be able to take this existing project which is not a Spring MVC application at the moment and treat it as though it was created as a Spring MVC template (kind of like wrapping the project in an STS MVC template). I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't decorate an existing project with Spring goodies just by importing it in to STS.

The best you can do is import and add the Spring project nature. This can be found by right-clicking on the project and selecting `Spring Tools --> Add Spring Project nature`.